# last-child for element which is wrapped within other parents?

Tags: html, css

I tried `hr:last-child` but it didn't work. Here's my HTML structure:

```html
    <div>
      <hr />
    </div>
    <div>
      <hr />
      // hide this
    </div>
```

It worked only if I have hr as siblings.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Only target the second hr? Why don't you just give the second div an ID or class name and then do something like: `.second-div hr { display: none }`

Comment: take a look how it can work [https://jsfiddle.net/L80p9rh6/](https://jsfiddle.net/L80p9rh6/)

Answer (score 2):

whilst you can target it by targetting the parent divs and using the direct-sibling combinator and then the hr inside it would be far better to either add classes or better yet - change the html. Also I would suggest csss for adding things like border-bottom, rather than hr html elements.

but here goes - target the divs that are siblings - then in the div that is not the first sibling - target the hr and hide it with display:none. still not the way i would do it though.

I have added text and padding in the divs to demonstre the hr is removed in the second option.

EDIT - actually - just thought of a simpler way .... but only if you want to hide them in ALL divs that are not the first one.

```
.hide-hr div:not(:first-child) hr{display:none};
```

```css
div {
padding: 5px
}

p {
margin: 0;
}

 div + div {
  border-top-width:0;
 }


.hide-hr {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.hide-hr div + div hr {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<p> the following shows the hr in the second div</p>

<div class="show-hr">
  <div>
    <p>div 1</p>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>div 2</p>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>


<p> the following hides the hr in the second div</p>
<div class="hide-hr">
  <div>
    <p>div 1</p>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>div 2</p>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ohhhh nice solution :)

Comment: will this work if you have 3 section?

Comment: if you were to have three sections then 2 and three would both be affected - if that is not desired - investigate the nth-of-type() selector or the nth-child() selector. or as noted above - change the code to be more manageable approach :) - glad to have helped though.

Comment: what's wrong with this solution ```div:last-child > hr {
  display: none;  
}```?

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the last div insted, and hide the hr in that

```css
div {
border :solid 1px red;
padding: 10px
}

hr {
  background: blue;
 }
 
 div + div {
  border-top-width:0;
 }

section div:last-child hr {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<section>
<div>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div>
  <hr/>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use :last--of-type

[last-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/)

```
hr:last-of-type {
 css here
}
```

Comment: it's not work, this css hide all the hr